# Why does std::setprecision(6) stream more than six digits in fixed-width mode?

Tags: c++, std, iostream, c++03

The output of the following code:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

inline string lexical_cast(const float arg)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << fixed << setprecision(numeric_limits<float>::digits10) << arg;
    if (!ss)
        throw "Conversion failed";

    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    cout << numeric_limits<float>::digits10 << '\n';
    cout << lexical_cast(32.123456789) << '\n';
}
```

is:

> 6
>   32.123455

I expected, and wanted:

> 6
>   32.1234

because, to the best of my knowledge, that's the extent of what a `float` can reliably give me on my system.

How can I persuade IOStreams to behave as I want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In fixed-width mode the "precision" setting is used as the number of decimal places, in contrast with scientific mode where it is used as the number of significant digits. IOStreams provides no mechanism to use "precision" as the number of significant digits without using scientific mode.

There is a third mode, which in C++11 is activated with `std::defaultfloat`. This "default" mode is what you get if you don't set either fixed or scientific mode. You can re-activate it in C++03 by resetting the float flags with `s.unsetf(std::ios_base::floatfield)`. This mode is a bit of a mix between scientific and some sort of "fixed without trailing zeros".

Comment: [Even in C++03, not specifying the mode seems to](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aeab7fb34a268215) result in [what cppreference says are C++11 `defaultfixed` semantics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed). Could you comment on that? It is defaulting to scientific notation and I just happen not to be triggering the exponent suffix? (Guess I could test that myself)

Comment: Yeah, [meh](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6bea22b08891ac7). :( Well, +1 from me for this conclusion that IOStreams 2003 is too limited to do what I want. Unless you can suggest a clever alternative... (then you still only get +1)

Comment: @Lightness I added a note about that. It's a weird mix of the two. Not quite.

Comment: Guess I'll stick with this then until exponent notation becomes a problem, then break my neck trying to figure something better... ta Robot      

Comment: Exponent notation just became a problem.