# Why my double is shown as scientific?

Tags: c++

How can I add a scientific and a float number  ? I have something like

```
 var1 0.99999899 var2  3.5008552e-05 sum  3.5008552e-05
```

but what I dont understand is why in the first place var2 is shown as scientific while in the first place I declared

```
double var1, var2;
```

so, actually their sum is just var2...

thanks

a

Comment: There's the [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) I/O manipulator.

Answer (score 7):

The way a floating-point value is displayed is down to the mechanism by which you display it. It is not a property of the value itself, nor is it in any way stored within the variable:

> A number is a number is a number. What you call "scientific" is not a class of numbers. It's a class of *representations of numbers*. The same way that "twelve" and "12" and "XII" and "a dozen" and "IIIIIIIIIIII" all represent the same number. This "scientific" thing only exists when you decide to represent the number in some specific way (i.e. when you output it). Calculations don't "turn numbers into scientific" the same way that saying that "2 * 6 is twelve" doesn't turn numbers into English words. The variables always store the numbers not the representations. — [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes)

Your display mechanism — `std::cout`? — is choosing the best way to output the value. You can override this with IO manipulators such as [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed), though [it's pretty fiddly sometimes to get it just how you want it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22150400/560648), due to library limitations.

Comment: And how can I store the "proper" sum value (ie after std::fixed) in a new variable ? The actual problem is not just to cout the sum rather than use it...

Comment: @Just_Newbie: Read my answer again. You don't "store" the manner of display. You store the value itself. If you use `std::fixed` on all your variables, you'll see exactly the value that they contain. This value is considered during all arithmetic operations, even if you're not seeing it in totality when you do a default `std::cout` operation. Do be aware though that if, even after all that, you're not seeing the precision you expect, that may simply be because you are underflowing your variable.

Comment: then there is no way to store it ?

Comment: @Just_Newbie: It feels like you're not listening to me. :( Is there another way I can explain this that may be clearer? Perhaps you could ask a more specific question about what you are trying to do and what is not happening.

Comment: ok - so, I define two doubles whose sum I want to store as a double (or float). My problem is that adding the scientific and the double numbers, dont give the correct answer..Is it better now ? thanks!

Comment: @Just_Newbie: No, that's what you already said in the question. Can you be [a lot] more specific? Give actual values. List the values you set, the values you read back, and tell us how they differ from what you wanted. Show the code that you use to accomplish your goal. http://sscce.org

Comment: ok - so, [code]var1= 0.999999 var2 = 2.90405e-05[/code] and the sum =  2.90405e-05, which as you can see sum = var2 actually. So var1 and var2 are actually computed from another formula. So, I guess if I can convert (not cout!) the var2 to double format rather than scientific, that would do the trick

Comment: @Just_Newbie: Ideally, transform your question so that it contains this crucial information, via _editing_. :)

Comment: @Just_Newbie "my problem is [...] adding the scientific and the double numbers" <- this makes exactly no sense.

Comment: Nope, you're _still_ thinking that "double format" and "scientific format" exist and are a property of the variable. They are not. The format has nothing to do with the value when it is stored. It is _only_ considered when you display it.

Comment: @Griwes as said, initially, BOTH var1 & var2 are declared as `double`. But after some calculation, var2 is shown up as scientific. So this is exactly the problem, adding what is a double with what now is shown as scientific

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Ok, now I get it -so that means, that even f I see the `sum = var2` while print on screen, actually `var2` holds the proper value - it is just for the display that it decides to shown up like this - correct ?

Comment: @Just_Newbie: Yes. With the caveat I mentioned before, which is that you _may_ be underflowing your arithmetic operation, though I don't think that's the case here given the numbers in play. I haven't tested it though because you didn't show us a [testcase](http://sscce.org) to play with!

Comment: A number is a number is a number. What you call "scientific" is not a class of numbers. It's a class of *representations of numbers*. The same way that "twelve" and "12" and "XII" and "a dozen" and "IIIIIIIIIIII" all represent the same number. This "scientific" thing only exists when you decide to represent the number in some specific way (i.e. when you output it). Calculations don't "turn numbers into scientific" the same way that saying that "2 * 6 is twelve" doesn't turn numbers into English words. The variables always store the numbers not the representations.

Answer (score -2):

If you have `<stdio.h>` available then you may use `int printf ( const char * format, ... );` the format specifier would look something like this: `printf("%.5f", your_double)` where 5 is the number of digits you want after the decimal point, the default is 6.
([printf docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)))

Comment: I don't think encouraging new C++ users to resort to outmoded C idioms is very responsible. Also, printing only six significant figures for a `double` is unlikely to be desired if you care about more precision than that (which, given the OP's values, is clear).